# can we say they are diagonal(always) or no?

Tags: linear-algebra

A and B are two matrix that commute with each other, 
AB=BA or [A,B]=0
can we  say they are diagonal(always) or no?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$ $$B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ where $b, c$ is non-zero.

Comment: Good example! Definitely more trivial than the one I thought up.

Answer (score 1):

Just because two matrices, $A$ and $B$ commute, they need not be diagonal. For example, let $A$ be any SYMMETRIC square matrix. Then, $AA^{T} = A^{T}A$. Hence, there is a whole family of matrices, which commute with their transposes, that are non-diagonal.

Comment: Forgot to say that the matrix, $A$, ought to be symmetric. Thanks for noticing my mistake.